# Can not see hotbar or crosshair

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can someone help me? I pressed a button (I don't know that button I pressed) and now I can't see my crosshair or hotbar anymore
(NOTE: Not in F1)

Answer (score 0):

You're in Spectator mode. Press F3+N or enter `/gamemode creative` into chat.

Comment: Im in survival mode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you activated a texture pack that removes the textures of hotbar, crosshair, items and some others.

This can also happen when you join a server.